# Is there anyway to create label in gmail without enabling imap in gmail settings

Tags: gmail, label, imap

I have created an android app using imap to create labels in gmail, but i need another way to create labels in gmail using java.

Thankz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may use the REST based Gmail API:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: Could you please provide me a sample program.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/samples/samples has samples in Python.  The API and links to samples in other languages are at http://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads